# Data Binding to convert mm to ft and inches or vice versa using Angularjs and ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I want to convert lenghts from mm to ft and inches or vice versa. User can input either mm or ft&in.The case is I always want to save data in mm to database but use angular to see it in both format.

I have already created a solution for it. http://plnkr.co/edit/thgx8vjsjxwfx6cLVVn1?p=preview 
But it is using ng-change everytime to convert the values.

I was wondering if some angular expert has better idea of doing similar stuff. Please note that I am only planning to save single value `$scope.lengthmm`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 // $scope.lengthtodb = 0;

  $scope.mmToFtIn =function(){

    toInch = $scope.lengthmm * 0.0393701;
    toFt = toInch/12;
    OutputFT = Math.floor(toFt);
    OutputInch = (toFt - Math.floor(toFt))*12;
    $scope.lengthft = OutputFT;
    $scope.lengthin = OutputInch;


    $scope.Result1 = OutputFT + "ft" + OutputInch + "Inches";


  };

   $scope.FtInTomm =function(){

    tomm = (($scope.lengthft *12)+  $scope.lengthin)*25.4;
    $scope.lengthmm = tomm;

     $scope.Result2 = tomm;


  };

});
```

In addition, as there will be lots of fields using the the same logic maybe method `mmToFTIn` needs to split in two methods to bind ft and inches separately. But I am really looking forward to see a smarted solution.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting the Output onto the view is best done with filters.

JS:

```
app.filter('inchFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return Math.floor(input * 0.0393701);
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<input name="mm" type="text" value="{{lengthmm | inchFilter}}">
```

Edit:

For a more complete and powerful solution I extended the plunker with a directive to now allow two-way-binding on the non-metric fields aswell.

```
app.directive('enhancedInput', function($parse){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl){
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(scope.$eval(attr.fromMm));
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(scope.$eval(attr.toMm));
    }
  };
});
```

This is achieved by first "requiring" the ngModelController and then using its $parsers and $formatters to intercept communication in between model and view.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZjgZ6zQTxITtvdyQLfv?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks nice solution!, is it possible to do it in either way. which means, user may write ft in and get mm ? And eventually this mm value will be saved.

Comment: Check out the Plunker again, I added a directive that does formatting and parsing with the ngModelController. http://plnkr.co/edit/NZjgZ6zQTxITtvdyQLfv?p=preview

Comment: This is something awesome! But you are converting ft and inches differently, where in my solution ft and inches are together, which means first it gets ft then inches are rest of it. As I am really new in angularjs and directive option I could not figure it out how can I re-edit it.

Comment: Now you're making it tricky :D How fast do you need an answer on this? I wouldn't mind investing some time this evening.

Comment: Hi, @ChristophHegemann could you please support me in this matter ? I am still stuck in this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a `$watch` on the millimeter variable and then update the inches model. This is probably a better option than ng-change because the `$watch` will fire any time the variable is changed within the scope, not just when the input to your text box changes.

I have created [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5RXuaL0LPxHp74Rs0hJc) for you. While you state you only wish to use one variable, I believe using a second variable in this manner is really the better approach. Alternatively you could use an object or an array to maintain a single variable while storing two values.

For this example I defined the variables as follows

```
    $scope.inches = 0;
    $scope.mm = 0;
```

Then we just create a watch on both variables. To reiterate, this function gets called any time there is a change to the `mm` variable which allows you to ensure that the relationship between `mm` and `inches` is maintained.

```
    $scope.$watch('mm', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      $scope.inches = newVal / 25.4;
    });
```

You could also [create a custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) as follows... this might even be a better solution if you only need to display `mm` in a formatted manner (as opposed to using it for calculations or something else).

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).filter('mmToInches', function() {
  return (function (input) {
    return (input / 25.4);
  });
});
```

Then later on do...

```
Inches Filter : {{ mm | mmToInches }}
```

You can add arguments to filters to a single filter can do both conversions.

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).filter('convert', function() {
  return (function (input, type) {
    if (type == 'mm2inch')
    {
      return (input / 25.4);
    } else if (type == 'inch2mm') {
      return (input * 25.4);
    }
  });
});

Inches Filter : {{ mm | convert:'mm2inch' }}
MM Filter : {{ inches | convert:'inch2mm' }}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution. is it possible to make the method/filter in two way data-binding logic. So user can write either mm or ft inches ? filter is a nice option as I can use it in many fields. I have at least 25 fields to convert this mm to ftin or vice versa. This is why I thought to use function to reuse it in all after some modification.

Comment: Use `$watch` for the two way data-binding logic. The preview includes a filter that parses inch and millimeter strings.

To clarify, at this point I believe you have the tools in your possession to accomplish the task at hand and it's a matter of design decisions. You need to provide more information if you wish for help with the design decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improvement I made to [Christoph Hegemann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080392/25080787#25080787).

The directive only uses one attribute, which points to a scope object `inchesShowFeet` (you can call it anything you want).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.beamLength" 
       ng-enhanced-input="inchesShowFeet" 
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }" />
```

The directive itself, as he mentioned, uses the ng-model attribute's parsers

```
app.directive('ngEnhancedInput', function($parse){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl){
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(scope.$eval(attr.ngEnhancedInput).store);
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(scope.$eval(attr.ngEnhancedInput).show);
    }
  };
});
```

The object, usually set in the controller, has a show and a store function. The name is funny, but it's the best I could think of. The one returns the value to **show** in the text box, the other one returns the value to **store** in the model.

```
$scope.inchesShowFeet = {
    show: function(val){ return val / 12; },
    store: function(val){ return val * 12; }
};
```

So, say I have `25` inches stored in my model. The *show* function get's called with a `val` of 25. It divides it by 12 and returns it, which get's displayed in the text box. When you type in `4`, the *store* function get's called with a `val` of 4. It multiplies it by 12 and returns 48, which get's stored in the model.